# Mongodb $match not accepting $lt

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am having problem trying to execute a simple mongodb aggregate method.

Below is my query,

```
var queryBuilder = {
        pID : new objectID(id),
        cIndex : { $lt : index }

    };
```

This is the aggregate method I am using,

```
alert.aggregate([
        {
            $match: queryBuilder
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$pName",
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                pTime: 1
            }
        }

    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
```

The same aggregate query works if I remove the "cIndex" entry. any idea what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Comment: What's not working about the query? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am not getting any error . The result is just empty. If i remove the "cIndex" i get full of data. and its a valid query. There are "cIndex" values right from 1.... till 100. I am just check if its less than 3 or 4

Comment: Do you have multiple documents for the given pID or its unique across all documents in the collection? if its unique then you must check cIndex value of document, if fits in your required value.

Comment: pID is like a reference, It is common over multiple documents. So if i query for a pID, i will receive [1....100] events, In that , every event has a cIndex value. I want to select "cIndex" which is less than some value.

Comment: can you share a sample of the dataset as well

Comment: can you try $match with the $and operator ?

Comment: Tried, its not working.